# Does anyone know how to solve the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/ludovic/netlib/lapack/LAPACK

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a distributed program using scala and spark and I'm getting this error, does anyone know how to solve it ? Thank a lot!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/ludovic/netlib/lapack/LAPACK
    at breeze.linalg.LU$primitive$LU_DM_Impl_Double$.apply(LU.scala:64)
    at breeze.linalg.LU$primitive$LU_DM_Impl_Double$.apply(LU.scala:56)
    at breeze.generic.UFunc.apply(UFunc.scala:47)
    at breeze.generic.UFunc.apply$(UFunc.scala:46)
    at breeze.linalg.LU$primitive$.apply(LU.scala:54)
    at breeze.linalg.det$$anon$1.apply(det.scala:18)
    at breeze.linalg.det$$anon$1.apply(det.scala:11)
    at breeze.generic.UFunc.apply(UFunc.scala:47)
    at breeze.generic.UFunc.apply$(UFunc.scala:46)
    at breeze.linalg.det$.apply(det.scala:9)
```

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: spark 3.3.0 and scala 2.13.0

Comment: are you testing locally or submiting your code to an external cluster

Answer (score 2):

It worked by just adding the blas and lapack dependencies to pom.xml file. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems like you are submitting your application in distributed environment. and the application is not able to find the dependency in the class-path.

You need to add the required jars in the class-path. You may use below option in spark-submit command to add the jar files in class-path.

```
--jars /path/to/first.jar,/path/to/second.jar,/path/to/third.jar
```